# msSQL: How do I replace NA values in different columns by different values?

Tags: sql-server, query, replace

Here is a example of a table:

```
    ID        Value1       Value2      Value3         
-----------------------------------------------------
1             1            2           NA
2             NA           3           NA
3             2            5           2
4             NA           NA          1
```

What is a query to replace NAs in column 'Value1' e.g. by 1, NAs in column 'Value2' by 3 and NAs in column 'Value3' by 2?

I think I'm looking for an equivalent to ISNULL function, but I don't find anything.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: What is the logic behind this pattern? I'm not seeing it, unless it's min - median - max.

Comment: you're right. The columns contain time series characteristica as std, min, max, linear modulated slope and I wish to give them a different 'default' value

Comment: I don't want to select the IDs as in the query, but replace the NA values in the database, where the table is stored..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query will replace the NA value in each column with the AVG value of non-NA rows in the data set. It uses a CTE and the UNION and PIVOT clauses to produce the 3 replacement values as a data set which is applied across the original table and CASE statements replace the original 'NA' values:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [Value1], [Value2], [Value3]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 'Value1' AS [Col],
            AVG(CAST(Value1 AS INT)) AS AvgValue
        FROM ValueData
        WHERE Value1 <> 'NA'
        UNION
        SELECT 'Value2' AS [Col],
            AVG(CAST(Value2 AS INT)) AS AvgValue
        FROM ValueData
        WHERE Value2 <> 'NA'
        UNION
        SELECT 'Value3' AS [Col],
            AVG(CAST(Value3 AS INT)) AS AvgValue
        FROM ValueData
        WHERE Value3 <> 'NA'
    ) src
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX([AvgValue]) FOR [Col] IN ([Value1], [Value2], [Value3])
    ) pvt
)

SELECT ID,
    CASE
        WHEN v.Value1 = 'NA' THEN c.Value1
        ELSE v.Value1
    END AS Value1,
    CASE
        WHEN v.Value2 = 'NA' THEN c.Value2
        ELSE v.Value2
    END AS Value2,
    CASE
        WHEN v.Value3 = 'NA' THEN c.Value3
        ELSE v.Value3
    END AS Value3
FROM ValueData v
CROSS APPLY CTE c
```

Results:

```
ID  Value1  Value2  Value3
--------------------------
1   1       2       1
2   1       3       1
3   2       5       2
4   1       3       1
```

I tested this against a dataset of 180,000 records and runtime was only 1 second so performance is not likely to be an issue.

I created a fake dataset using this code for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE ValueData (
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    Value1 VARCHAR(10),
    Value2 VARCHAR(10),
    Value3 VARCHAR(10)
)
GO

DECLARE @Val1 INT,
    @Val2 INT,
    @Val3 INT

SET @Val1 = CAST(ROUND(RAND()*3, 0) AS INT)
SET @Val2 = CAST(ROUND(RAND()*3, 0) AS INT)
SET @Val3 = CAST(ROUND(RAND()*3, 0) AS INT)

INSERT INTO ValueData (Value1, Value2, Value3)
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN @Val1 = 0 THEN 'NA'
        ELSE CAST(@Val1 AS VARCHAR(10))
    END AS Value1,
    CASE
        WHEN @Val2 = 0 THEN 'NA'
        ELSE CAST(@Val2 * (CAST(ROUND(RAND()*3, 0) AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR(10))
    END AS Value2,
    CASE
        WHEN @Val3 = 0 THEN 'NA'
        ELSE CAST(@Val3 / ((CAST(ROUND(RAND()*3, 0) AS INT) + 1)*2)+1 AS VARCHAR(10))
    END AS Value3
GO 180000
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed help! Actually this helps me a lot!